# Get SpreadSheetApp Id through webapp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have Add-On and WebApp, I want to read active spreadsheetapp Id in webapp but not able to do it, getting error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Kindly help me to correct the code as I am new to Javascript/JSON.

Add-On:

```
function onOpen(e) {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('DataQ')
      .addItem('Submit to Manager', 'copyData')
      .addToUi();
}

//Backup data to master spreadsheet.  
function copyData() {
 var ss_id = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  
  //This is the Web App URL.
  var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/xyz/exec";  

  var payload = {    
    "ss_id" : JSON.stringify(ss_id),    
  }

  var options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    "payload" : payload,
    "followRedirects" : true,
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
  };

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);   
}
```

WebApp

```
function doPost(e) {

  var ss_id = JSON.parse(e.parameters.ss_id);  

  var response = {
    "status" : "FAILED",
    "ss_id" : ss_id,
  };  

  var ss_id = ss_id[0];
  
  var dss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1vMeoANf6JJ8w0MP2DHJ6oTC4');
  var dsh=dss.getSheetByName('Consolidated_Data');

  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow()+1,1,sData.length,sData[0].length).setValues(sData);

  var FrontDesk_ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss_id);
  var FrontDesk_sheet = FrontDesk_ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  FrontDesk_sheet.getRange('D1:D20').setValue('Done');
  
  var response = {
    "status" : "SUCCESS",
    "sData" : sData,
  };     

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(response));

}
```

Comment: Which like is causing the error? Is it this one: `var ss_id = JSON.parse(e.parameters.ss_id);` If I'm correct, try removing the `JSON.parse()` function from there, you're parsing what's already an object and not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modification points:

- In your function of `copyData()`, `ss_id` is sent as `"payload" : {"ss_id" : JSON.stringify(ss_id)},`. In this case, at the `doPost(e)` side, `e.postData.contents`, `e.parameters.ss_id`, and `e.parameter.ss_id` are `ss_id=%22{Spreadsheet ID}%22`, `["\"{Spreadsheet ID}\""]` and `\"{Spreadsheet ID}\"`, respectively.
- By this, when the value of Spreadsheet ID is retrieved from this event object, the double quotes of `"` are required to be removed.
- But, when I saw your script of `doPost`, you use `var ss_id = JSON.parse(e.parameters.ss_id)`. In this case, `ss_id` is dthe Spreadsheet ID. But, you use `var ss_id = ss_id[0]` after `var ss_id = JSON.parse(e.parameters.ss_id)`. By this, `ss_id` is the 1st character of Spreadsheet ID. I think that this might be an issue of your script.

In this answer, in order to send and use Spreadsheet ID in your script, I would like to propose to modify both `copyData()` and `doPost(e)` as follows.

### Modified script:

#### `copyData()`

Please modify `copyData()` as follows.

From:

```
var payload = {
  "ss_id" : JSON.stringify(ss_id),
}
```

To:

```
var payload = {
  "ss_id" : ss_id, // Modified
}
```

#### `doPost(e)`

Please modify `doPost(e)` as follows.

From:

```
var ss_id = JSON.parse(e.parameters.ss_id);  

var response = {
  "status" : "FAILED",
  "ss_id" : ss_id,
};  

var ss_id = ss_id[0];
```

To:

```
var ss_id = e.parameter.ss_id; // Modified

var response = {
  "status" : "FAILED",
  "ss_id" : ss_id,
};

// var ss_id = ss_id[0]; // Removed
```

### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)